# How to make methods inside a constructor reference its argument?

Tags: javascript

I am asked to implement the `getSpeed`, `accelerate`, and `decelerate` methods of the constructor `Car`. When those methods are called, speed changes accordingly. I tried `this.speed` +/- `acceleration` or `arguments` but still didn't work.

```
var Car = function (acceleration) {

  var speed = 0;

  this.getSpeed = function () {
    return speed; 
  }

  this.accelerate = function () {
    return this.speed + arguments;
  }

  this.decelerate = function () {
    return this.speed - arguments;

  }
}

var honda = new Car(10);
console.log(honda.getSpeed()); // -> 0

honda.accelerate(); 
console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 10


honda.accelerate();
console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 20


honda.decelerate();
console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 10
```

Comment: `arguments` is an array-like collection of the values passed to a function call. You can't just add/subtract it to/from the speed. Also, `this.speed` isn't defined at all. You probably want `speed += arguments[0]` and `speed -= arguments[0]` respectively.

Comment: Welcome. We would like you to accept the best answer in this question or the answer that solved and explained your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning a new value to `speed` go with `-=` and `+=` instead of - and +

```
  this.getSpeed = function () {

   return speed; 
  }

  this.accelerate = function () {

  return speed += acceleration;
  }

  this.decelerate = function () {

  return speed -= acceleration;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes, first one you use a `var` declaration for a `speed` but in the method try get access to it by `this.speed`.
Second one it's you need to change value `this.speed += this.acceleration` in `accelerate` method.

```
var Car = function (acceleration) {
  this.acceleration = acceleration;

  this.speed = 0;

  this.getSpeed = function () {
   return this.speed; 
  }

  this.accelerate = function () {
    this.speed += this.acceleration;
  }

  this.decelerate = function () {
    this.speed -= this.acceleration;
  }
}

var honda = new Car(10);

console.log(honda.getSpeed()); // -> 0


honda.accelerate();

console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 10


honda.accelerate();

console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 20

honda.decelerate();

console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You got something wrong. After you do `accelerate()` 1 time, it will return 10, but after that it will return 10 again and again and again. And if you use `decelerate()`, it would go to -10. If you use it again it will go to -10 again.

```
var Car = function (acceleration) {

  this.acceleration = acceleration;
  this.speed = 0;

  this.getSpeed = function () {

    return this.speed; 
  }

  this.accelerate = function () {
    return this.speed += this.acceleration;
  }

  this.decelerate = function () {
    return this.speed -= this.acceleration;
  }
}

var honda = new Car(10);

console.log(honda.getSpeed()); // -> 0


honda.accelerate();

console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 10


honda.accelerate();

console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 20


honda.decelerate();

console.log(honda.getSpeed());// -> 10
```

After that, it sets first from 0 and then 10 and sets it to 10 and then so on...

You also forgot to set `this.speed` to 0. You only used `var speed=0`.

For `accelaration`, you have to use `this` in the functions otherwise it wouldn't be defined.

So basically you got 3 things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right way of doing it. putting the methods in the `prototype` so the next time you instantiate a Car constructor function it won't recreate those methods but instead will be referencing to its prototype chain.

```
const Car = function(speedo){
     this.speed = 0;
     this.speedo = speedo
}

Car.prototype.getSpeed = function () {
    return this.speed;
}

Car.prototype.accelerate = function () {
    this.speed += this.speedo;
  }

Car.prototype.decelerate = function () {
    this.speed -= this.speedo;
  }


var myAwesomeFreakNew = new Car(1000);
console.log(myAwesomeFreakNew.getSpeed())

myAwesomeFreakNew.accelerate();
console.log(myAwesomeFreakNew.getSpeed())

myAwesomeFreakNew.accelerate();
console.log(myAwesomeFreakNew.getSpeed())

myAwesomeFreakNew.decelerate();
console.log(myAwesomeFreakNew.getSpeed())
```

Comment: No, it is not. You only defined `speed` for the constructor, you didn't define it for other functions. So there is no `this.speed`. This also would produce errors.

Comment: ohh yea. forgot to do the `this.speed` and `this.speedo` my bad will edit